# Form.target = window.opener.name not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this function in my parent file:

```
$(function () {
$('#xybutton').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.name = 'parentwindow';
    var popupwindow = window.open(
        'popup.php',
        '',
        'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,' +
        'menubar=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,' +
        'width=600,' +
        'height=400'
        );
    if(window.focus){
        popupwindow.focus();
    }
});
});
```

I have a form in my popup window

```
<form method="post" action="newdoc.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ajax lock-page" id="xyform" name="xyform">
```

I have this function in corresponding js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#xyform').target = 'parentwindow'; //I also tried window.opener.name
console.log(window.opener.name); //This prints parentwindow
});
```

But still the form's result opens in the popup window rather than opening in parent.
Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: What is expected result? `.target` is not a jQuery method

Comment: Oops! Thanks. I didn't know that. The expected result is that the result of form submission must open in parent window. Thanks. Now it works fine. I changed it to .attr('target','parentwindow').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the property `.target` on the jQuery object, which has no meaning.

What you probably need is this:

```
$('#xyform').attr('target', 'parentwindow');
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$('#xyform').get(0).target = 'parentwindow';
```

The latter uses `get` which gives you the underlying DOM object (the first one in this case, to be exact - which is the only one anyway because you are selecting by ID). This can also be used to access other properties in case they are not accessible through jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for alternate solution. Quite useful. :)

Comment: You can also access the underlying Dom element using the array literal syntax `$('selector')[0].target`